# Class inside of Div not showing properly

Tags: html, css

so here's my problem, I have a `div` named `tiles` and inside this div is multiple classes, `tile-small` and `tile-large`. Now each of these classes have different properties, class `tile-large` for example has a larger width value while `tile-small` has a smaller width value, now these properties seem to be displaying correctly, however, each class has it's `background-color` property defined by the div, `tiles`. The multiple classes should be showing a background color of `#fff`, class `tile-large` seems to be showing the background color, but class `tile-small` is not. How do I correct my code and get both classes to show the background color I defined in the div?

Below is the whole HTML code; (With the CSS values in a `<style>` tag.)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>NowFootball | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <style>
    @font-face { font-family: title; src: url('fonts/title.ttf'); } 
    body {background-color: #efefef;margin-top: 15px;}
    ::selection {
  background: #93CC04; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #93CC04; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
    #content {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 97%;
    }
    #tiles {
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 200px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-top: auto;
        border: 0px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px #CCC, 0 5px 5px -5px #CCC, -5px 0 5px -5px #CCC;
    }
    .tile-large {
        background-color: #C4E66E;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .tile-small {
        background-color: #C4E66E;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50%;
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
    .center-text {
        text-align: center;
        color: #1f1f1f;
    }
    .left-text {
        float: left;
        color: #F7F7F7;
        line-height: 40px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-family: title;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    h2 {
        line-height: 100px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
        <div id="tiles">
            <div class="tile-large"><p class="left-text">Is there football on Wednesday?</p></div>
            <h2 class="center-text">Yes, there is football on Wednesday the 14th of January.</h2>

            <div class="tile-small"><p class="left-text">Attending Players</p></div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an image displaying my problem.

[image]

As you can see, the second class (The green bar under the white box) doesn't have the background color added to it.

below is what I want my code to display;

[image]

Comment: I really don't get it... you're setting `height:200px;` to the parent #tiles and asking why your `.tile-small` has no white background? (Also while asking questions try to be more descriptive use *color names* to make your question more understandable)

Comment: What I am trying to work out is why my tile-small class isn't exactly like the tile-large class, the large tile (seen in the picture shows correctly, what I want is to have an exact copy of this tile, but smaller width.

Comment: Do you realize that you wrapped BOTH your `.tile-***` into the white shadowed backgrounded parent `#tiles` ? Than you've set that parent a height of `200px` and expecting the child `-small` to have the white background?

Comment: I've updated my question to include an image of what I am trying to achieve. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said already in my comments to your questions, you cannot do what you do. it's completely wrong.

Instead here's a good (simplified) example how to style your CSS, with the desired result:

```css
*{margin:0;}

h3{ /*Style your selectors here, not all around the stylesheet*/
  background: #C4E66E;
  padding: 0.7em;
}
p{ /* Styles for all your paragraph elements */
  padding: 0.4em 0.7em;
}
#content{ /* no white background or similar. it's a container, use it as such */
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 97%;
}
.tile{    /* General .tile styles (applies to all .tile) */
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCC;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 1%;
}
.tile-large{ width: 98%; } /* Than create an additional class for "large" ones */
.tile-small{ width: 48%; } /* and for "small" ones */
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <div class="tile tile-large">
    <h3>Is there football on Wednesday?</h3>
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>

  <div class="tile tile-small">
    <h3>Attending Players</h3>
    <p>Hello CSS</p>
    <p>
      Hello again and another paragraph here<br>
      Lorem ipsum sackus overflovius
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="tile tile-small">
    <h3>match results</h3>
    <p>
      Hello again and another paragraph here<br>
      Lorem ipsum sackus overflovius
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was asking for! You're help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @MyNameIsNotSoCool you're welcome! Please consider all the comments in my code example. Also if you'll have issues with floated elements take a look at answers `How to properly clear floats` or find a `Micro float hack` (called .clearfix). Or simply wrap your rows inside a parent with `clear: both;` to prevent other elements below to stack in the wrong place. Happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a non-question. The `#fff` styling for the `#tiles` div will apply to all elements that aren't overridden. So if you had more text below `.tile-small`, the white background of `#tiles` would apply to this.

Answer (score -1):

Change your css and html to this.  It will display how you want it.

```
<style>
@font-face { font-family: title; src: url('fonts/title.ttf'); } 
body {background-color: #efefef;margin-top: 15px;}
::selection {
background: #93CC04; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
background: #93CC04; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
#content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 97%;
}
#tiles {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    border: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px #CCC, 0 5px 5px -5px #CCC, -5px 0 5px -5px #CCC;
}
#tiles2 {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    border: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px #CCC, 0 5px 5px -5px #CCC, -5px 0 5px -5px #CCC;
}
.tile-large {
    background-color: #C4E66E;
    height: 50px;
}
.tile-small {
    background-color: #C4E66E;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;

}
.center-text {
    text-align: center;
    color: #1f1f1f;
}
.left-text {
    float: left;
    color: #F7F7F7;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: title;
    font-size: 18px;
}
h2 {
    line-height: 100px;
}
</style>
```

and Change your HTML to

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="tiles">
        <div class="tile-large"><p class="left-text">Is there football on Wednesday?</p></div>
        <h2 class="center-text">Yes, there is football on Wednesday the 14th of January.</h2>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="tiles2">
        <div class="tile-small"><p class="left-text">Attending Players</p></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You got a downvote probably cause your answer is an overdose of CSS styles and unnecessary ID's. Clearly not a good practice to follow.

Comment: I guess instead of taking his code and just flipping it around i should have rewrote it the correct way.  While that does display correctly, it is vile; you are correct on that.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you are manually setting a height for the tiles div and the content extends below that point. The background will only be 200 pixels high as pointed out by Adam, even though the content will continue past where the background stops.

However, if what you really want to do is have the background match the height of all the content, leave out that line entirely. Simply change the tiles style to:

```
#tiles {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    border: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px #CCC, 0 5px 5px -5px #CCC, -5px 0 5px -5px #CCC;
}
```

I've attached a jsfiddle link to demonstrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/hytvg22c/

Comment: This does not answers the question at all. The OP is missing some basic knowledge of structuring HTML code and styling elements with CSS

Comment: No, no. The top tile displays how I want it too, I want to have an exact copy of the tile but with a smaller width value, I've added an extra image above to demonstrate what I am trying to get to work :) thanks for offering your help!

Comment: It's not that it didn't answer the question, it's that the question was poorly framed.

With elaboration, though, it is clear that your answer is what he needs now, Roko.